# how to remove local storage value from private browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser-cache

how to remove local storage value from private browser?

Here it is my code which is working fine, but it is also working on private window event i don't want to work on that.

### $(".browser_cache_save").click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); //alert("h"); localStorage.setItem('name', 'Matt West'); $("#cachesaveid").remove(); }) window.onload = function(){ var name = localStorage.getItem('name'); if (name != "undefined" || name != "null") { $("#cachesaveid").remove(); } }

Comment: you can use **localStorage.removeItem(key);**

Comment: Or `window.localStorage.removeItem(key);`

Comment: but what should i write condition for remove key in private browser ? l